# Shell scripting - if statement difference

Tags: bash, shell, unix

This a question of an exercise:
What is the difference between the two "if" instructions?

```
#!/bin/bash
rm tmp
echo -n > tmp
for f in $*
do
        if test ! -f $f
        then
                echo $f does not exist as a file
                continue
        fi
        rm $f

        if [ ! -f $f ]
        then
                echo $f has been deleted successfully
        fi
        ls $f >> tmp
done
x='cat tmp | grep -c ^.*$'
echo result: $x
```

Comment: What do you think the answer is?

Comment: nothing different

Comment: but what does "test" stand for? how is that interpreted?

Comment: Take a look at `man test`.

Comment: You got the answer you were asking for but your script has multiple bugs related to not following shell programming fundamentals (e.g. `$*` vs `"$@"`, unquoted variables, deprecated backticks). Post a new question if you'd like help with fixing those.

Comment: this was an exercise. probably it was very easy for those who write regularly  shell scripts and have it in mind all the time, but i will not pump your rating higher, man... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The square brackets are a synonym for the test command, instead of `if test ! -f $f` we can use `if [ ! -f $f ]`.
 Note: `test` is a command which takes expression and test or evaluates.

Answer (score 1):

No difference. `test` and `[` are builtins in most (all?; definitely in dash, bash, yash, ksh, zsh, fish) shells now:

```
$ type [ 
[ is a shell builtin
$ type test
test is a shell builtin
```

There's also executable versions of them:

```
$ which [
/usr/bin/[
$ which test
/usr/bin/test
```

Unlike `cd`, `test` (or `[`) doesn't need to be a builtin (at least not for the common options -- some shells' extensions require it to be a builtin), but the fork+exec overhead of an external executable is too much for the little things that `test` tests.